# Problem with edit and align viral whole genomes

Tags: sequence-alignment, whole-genome

I have a database of whole genome of African swine fever virus (about 190kb/genome) downloaded from GenBank. But these sequences do not start at the same place on the genome. When I align the sequence to build a phylogenetic tree. The sequences at the 3' and 5' ends have many gaps and do not match. The length of the entire data set is over 220kb due to many gaps.
Kindly suggest me a solution to the problem.

Comment: Welcome! Can you post an image of your alignment?